# JavaScript "for" loop selecting JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json

OKAYSO, I'm working with some JSON data and formatting it into the DOM, and I'm trying to avoid stuff that looks like this...

```
var image1 = content.list.story[1].image[0].crop[1].src;
var image2 = content.list.story[1].image[0].crop[1].src;
var image3 = content.list.story[2].image[0].crop[1].src;
var image4 = content.list.story[3].image[0].crop[1].src;
```

To avoid that, I'm using the following for loop

```
var count ;
for(count = 0; count < 1; count++){
   console.log("content.list.story["+[count]+"].image[0].crop[1].src");
};
```

That code prints

```
content.list.story[0].image[0].crop[1].src
```

**Exactly** as it should. However, when I format it to print the actual resource, as such...

```
var count ;
for(count = 0; count < 1; count++){
   console.log(content.list.story['+[count]+'].image[0].crop[1].src);
};
```

...it returns undefined.

Any idea what I'm screwing up here?

Comment: `content.list.story[count].image[0].crop[1].src`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
var count ;
for(count = 0; count < 1; count++){
    console.log(content.list.story[count].image[0].crop[1].src);
};
```

You should use variable with index, in your example, you had put index "[count]" and correct index is "0".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using index from 1 to 4 and you are using 0 in loop. So the array[0] is undefined.

Also even if JSON index begins at 0, the code should be like below, note using "story[count]" not story['+[count]+']

```
var count ;
for(count = 0; count < 1; count++){
   console.log(content.list.story[count].image[0].crop[1].src);
};
```

Comment: Negative. JSON index begins at 0.

Answer (score 1):

try the code below:

```
  var count ;
 for(count = 0; count < 1; count++){
   console.log(content.list.story[count].image[0].crop[1].src);
 };
```